# Python - Threading - Make sure that Timer() stops correctly

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to make sure that my timer correctly stops after running `timer.cancel()`, but I am not sure if I'm doing this correctly. To my knowledge, first you stop it by running `cancel()`, and then wait until the thread is completely cleaned up and terminated, using `join()`. If I run `join()` after canceling, any statements after `join()` will be executed only after the thread is completely terminated. Am I understanding this correctly?

If not, how do I make sure that my thread is terminated completely, and that my next lines of code will run only after the thread's termination?

```
def f():
    timer = threading.Timer(5, f)

    if something_happens:
        timer.cancel()
        timer.join()

        do_something_after_timer_completely_stops()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cancel timer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985211/cancel-timer-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `.join()`. Calling `.cancel()` is enough to stop the timer. However, there's a caveat: Timers can only be stopped if they are in the **waiting** stage (before the time expires). If the actual code is already running it can't be stopped anymore by `.cancel()`; It becomes a normal thread.

The way the `threading.Timer()` class is implemented uses a `threading.Event` instance that is waited upon, to allow cancelling the timer, however if the timer runs out the event is only set after the function has finished. So you can't use it to reliably detect if the thread has started. I suggest creating your own event object if you want to be notified that.

Example: You're creating a timer to call `f`:

```
timer = threading.Timer(5, f)
```

Instead, create a new event and a function to set it before calling `f`, and schedule your timer to call that new function you created.

```
f_called = threading.Event()
def calls_f(*args, **kwds):
    """function that calls f after setting the event f_called"""
    f_called.set()
    return f(*args, **kwds)

timer = threading.Timer(5, calls_f)
```

Then you can use that event to check if `f` was already called:

```
if f_called.is_set():
     print("Too bad, thread is already running, can't cancel the timer!")
```

Comment: could you tell me how to check if the timer is in waiting stage, or the code is running? So like, how can I be notified if my `.cancel()` code will properly work?